# Load a collection in Router's initialize function and prevent of other functions evaluation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new in Backbone and I would appreciate your feedback on the below

What I want to achieve, is to render a list of items on page load and to have the following functionality:

1. OnLoad render the list
2. On Item's doubleClick I want to render a new view and navigate to a new route "edit/:id"
3. On Page load, if the URL has the 'edit/:id' then the appropriate function I would like to be triggered.

So far I have done the items 1 and 2 of the list and I can't come with a nice way to do the number 3. 
My problem is that on pageLoad I fetch() the Collection from server and I am rendering the appropriate view (item 1 in the list), but if I have this 'edit/:id' in the URL, then the Router is getting initialized before the collection fetches it's data and this produces an 'undefined' error. I've tried to load the collection in the 'initialize' function of the Router() (which I don't like it as an idea cause is the same code in more than one place)  but it didn't work.

**This is the code I have so far**

*Model*

```
var Commercial = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/commercials',
    selected: function(){
       this.collection.selectItem(this);
    }
});
```

*Collection*

```
var Commercials = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: '/commercials',

model: Commercial,

selectItem: function(model){
    vents.trigger('comm:selected', model);
}
});
```

*Router*

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    'edit/:id' : 'editCommercial'
},
initialize: function(){
           //I tried this but with no luck. If I go on this way, I have somehow to say to the collection to load the list Synchronously
            //Also, I don't like this implementation.
    commercials.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    this.collection =  commercials;
                }
            });
},
editCommercial: function(id){
    var model =  this.collection.get(id);
    if(model){
        model.selected();
    }
}
});
```

*View*

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#commercials',

events: {
    'dblclick tr' :'editView',
    'click .delete' : 'deleteRecord'
},
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('remove',this.render,this);
    this.collection.on('add',this.render,this);
},
render: function() {
    var templatehb = Handlebars.templates["commercials"];
    this.$el.html(templatehb({
        items:this.collection.toJSON()
    }))
},
editView: function(ev) {
    var $this = $(ev.target);
    var id = $this.parents('tr').data('id');
    if(id){
        var model = this.collection.get(id);
        model.selected(this);           
    }
}
});
```

*Initialize*

```
var vents = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);

var commercials = new Commercials({
   vents: vents
});

var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();

vents.on("comm:selected", function(model){
    var editView = new EditView({model:model,vents:vents});
    editView.render();
    //**this works just fine**
    router.navigate('edit/'+model.get('id'));
});

vents.on("comm:bindList", function(){
    commercials.fetch({
        success: function(){
           var listView = new ListView({collection:commercials});
           listView.render();
        }
    });
 });


/*Load the main view*/
vents.trigger('comm:bindList');
```

Ideally I would like to set my in my Page (my views) that are depended on a collection, and that I have to wait until this collection is finishing fetching data.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using deferreds:

```
  vents.on("comm:bindList", function(){
    commercials.xhr = commercials.fetch();
    commercials.xhr.done(function(){
           var listView = new ListView({collection:commercials});
           listView.render();
        }
    });
 });

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        'edit/:id' : 'editCommercial'
    },
    editCommercial: function(id){
        commercials.xhr.done(function(){
            var model =  commercials.get(id);
            if(model){
                model.selected();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I wrote more about deferreds on my blog:

- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/
- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried with xhr before reading your posts and I got an 'undefined' error. Obviously I have to read them. Will come back soon.. :)